# How to strip a certain piece of text from each line of a text file?

Tags: python, text, strip, machine-translation

I have downloaded the tab-separated tatoeba dataset with English-German sentence pairs to train an NMT model on it. Unfortunately each line ends with all sorts of additional information:

```
Go. Geh.    CC-BY 2.0 (France) Attribution: tatoeba.org #2877272 (CM) & #8597805 (Roujin)
Hi. Hallo!  CC-BY 2.0 (France) Attribution: tatoeba.org #538123 (CM) & #380701 (cburgmer)
```

**How can I strip the part after the second sentence for each line in the text file?**

I tried doing it in python:

```
for line in text:
  split = line.split('CC-BY', 1)
  line = split[0]
```

...but that didn't work. What I'm looking for is a file that looks like this:

```
Go. Geh.
Hi. Hallo!
```

For any help I would be very grateful :)

Comment: Splitting doesn't seem the logical thing to me here, and I'd just use `.find()` with string indexing/slicing e.g.: `segment = line[:line.find('CC-BY')].rstrip()`

Comment: What isn't working specifically? If I do `print(line)` at the end of each iteration of the for-loop, I get the desired output. Are you asking how to output the extracted lines to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of using `split` is correct but assigning directly in this way in a for loop will not change the list elements.

You should also avoid using `split` as a variable name when it is already the name of an inbuilt method.

A list comprehension will do the job:

```
new_lines = [line.split('CC-BY', 1)[0].strip() for line in text]
```

The `strip` is added because you probably want to remove the extra spaces at the end of each line.

---

With your input text saved as `text.txt`, the following code:

```
with open("text.txt", encoding="utf8") as f:
    text = f.read().splitlines()

new_lines = [line.split('CC-BY', 1)[0].strip() for line in text]

for line in new_lines:
    print(line)
```

gives the output:

```
Go. Geh.
Hi. Hallo!
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, unfortunately I wasn't able to make the code work. I ran it and the result looks something like this: ['G', 'o', '.', '', 'G', 'e', 'h', '.', '', 'C', 'C', '-', 'B', 'Y', '', '2', '.', '0', '', '(', 'F', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'c', 'e', ')', '', 'A', 't', 't', 'r', 'i', 'b', 'u', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', ......]

Comment: You probably didn't split the input into lines. Please see the answer edited above with the full code.

Answer (score 1):

I enjoy Python, but I would not do this in Python.  You can just **use `bash`** to slice the first 2 columns:

```
cut -f1 -f2 tatoeba.en.de.tsv
```

(Assuming the file is called *tatoeba.en.de.tsv*.)

To pipe it into a file:

```
cut -f1 -f2 tatoeba.en.de.tsv > tatoeba.en.de.stripped.tsv
```

Advantages over naïve Python approaches:

- `cut` is easier to use, more readable and less code.
- `cut` does not load the whole file into memory, so it can handle really large files.
- `>` will write only the output into the file, not error messages.

The fact that tabs are a first-class citizen in core bash utils is one big reason for choosing [TSV for machine translation data](https://modelfront.com/docs/formats/linear-tsv#why-tsv).

---

If you really want to do it in Python, so that it works with any Tatoeba file contents or size:

- split on tab and use `slice` or slice notation, do *not* split on a value like `CC-BY` and do *not* strip
- read from an iterator, do *not* read all the lines into an object

```
filename = sys.argv[1] # Pass the name of the file
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        source, target = line.split('\t')[:1] # "slice" the first 2 columns
        print(source, target, sep='\t')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response – your approach seems to be the more efficient way of tackling this task. However, the data from tatoeba is delivered in a .txt format, not .tsv, so doing it the way the commenter above you suggested was simply easier for me with the limited programming knowledge I have, which is why he received the checkmark.

Comment: @Zwiebak Tatoeba files are actually TSV files - i.e. the column separator is tab - regardless of the file extension used.  You can just change the file extension on your machine from .txt to .tsv, or change the filename in the code above to match the files you have.

Comment: Ok that's very good to know! Thank you for you help :)